# Map marker icons are not loading using Picasso

Tags: android

I am trying to load marker icons from URL but it's not showing me the icons on a map.What thing I am doing wrong.When I am using Bitmap to load icons it's working.
Picasso image load is not working for me.

I got the item name in a log:

> >
>         ....
>           D/success:  @+ Set bitmap for Duke Of Wellington PT size: #3
>           D/success:  @+ Set bitmap for Dante Gabriel Rossetti PT size: #2
>           D/success:  @+ Set bitmap for Pierre Teilhard de Chardin PT size: #1

Here is my complete code :

```
private class CreateProductListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Product>> {

    private String serverUrl;

    public CreateProductListTask(String url) {
        super();
        this.serverUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Product> doInBackground(Void... params) {
             .....

            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString());

            List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, Bitmap> iconsMap = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                JSONArray productsJSON = response.getJSONArray("all_products");
                for (int ixProduct = 0; ixProduct < productsJSON.length(); ixProduct++) {
                    JSONObject productJSON = productsJSON.getJSONObject(ixProduct);
                    String mapIconStr = productJSON.getString("map_icon");
                    URI uri = new URI(mapIconStr);
                    String[] segments = uri.getPath().split("/");
                    String iconName = segments[segments.length - 1];

                    // percetn-encode URL
                    String mapIconPath = mapIconStr.substring(0, mapIconStr.indexOf(iconName));
                    String iconUrlString = mapIconPath + URLEncoder.encode(iconName, "UTF-8");

                    // replace "http:" with "https:"
                    iconUrlString = iconUrlString.replace("http:", "https:");

                        try {
                            Product product = new Product();
                            product.id = productJSON.getString("ID");
                            product.name = productJSON.getString("post_title");
                            product.lat = productJSON.getDouble("latitude");
                            product.lon = productJSON.getDouble("longitude");
                            id = product.id;
                            System.out.println("my Id stored" + id);

                            product.icons= iconUrlString;
                            products.add(product);

                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                        }

                }

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Log.e("App", "Failure", ex);
            }

            return products;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("App", "yourDataTask", ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Product> products) {
        if (products != null) {
            PoiTarget pt;
            for (final Product product : products) {

                Marker marker = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(product.lat, product.lon))
                        .title(product.name)
                       /* .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(product.icon))*/);

                pt = new PoiTarget(marker);
                poiTargets.add(pt);
                Picasso.with(Frnt_mapActivity.this)
                        .load(product.icons)
                        .into(pt);
                markerIds.put(marker, product.id);


            }
        }
    }

}
//--------------------------------------------------------
// Inner class
//--------------------------------------------------------
class PoiTarget implements Target {
    private Marker m;

    public PoiTarget(Marker m) { this.m = m; }

    @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        m.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        poiTargets.remove(this);
       Log.d("success"," @+ Set bitmap for "+m.getTitle()+" PT size: #"+poiTargets.size());
    }

    @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
       Log.e("Load Image Failed"," @+ [ERROR] Don't set bitmap for "+m.getTitle());
        poiTargets.remove(this);
    }

    @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Glide for this purpose , it loads bitmap faster than picasso. Sometimes picasso throws error while loading but in Glide this thing does not happens.

also Dont forget to close and reopen the marker after loading the image. See code below.

```
 if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
    marker.hideInfoWindow();
    marker.showInfoWindow();
}
```

let me know if you still have confusion . i will post my full code.

Comment: can you give me an example? How can I use it?

Comment: Here is my code on Google drive for the fragement that contains map functionality. 
Try and let me know your doubts.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ptPpN3vTh7RjNjMjQtMFlPYk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you are using too many things. Can you explain it with my code so that it is easy for me to understand?

Comment: addMarker, getMarkerDrawable and onMapReady Methods are for your use . DealModel can be replaced by a HashMap also. 
For example: model.getImage() can be replaced by hashmap.get("your string name");

Comment: firstly get all the data that you have to show on fragment , then use my code to show that.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this code

```
@Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        m.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        poiTargets.remove(this);
       Log.d("success"," @+ Set bitmap for "+m.getTitle()+" PT size: #"+poiTargets.size());
    }
```

with

```
@Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        poiTargets.remove(this);
        m.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));

       Log.d("success"," @+ Set bitmap for "+m.getTitle()+" PT size: #"+poiTargets.size());
    }
```

Comment: why you use `poiTargets.remove(this);` before `m.setIcon(..)`?

Comment: i think poiTargets.remove(this);  remiving added marker thats  why i use poiTargets.remove(this); before m.setIcon(..)